# What will happen to our Mac if using higher RAM than Apple "allows" it?

Tags: mac, memory

I am thinking to upgrade my RAM to be 16GB. However Apple states up to 8GB only.

Anyone has experience upgraded RAM more than Apple allows?

Comment: Depends on the exact model. Some will take more than Apple says, some will not.

Comment: well my mac pro is early 2011

Comment: There is no "Early 2011" Mac Pro

Comment: Either you have Mid 2010 or Mid 2012 model, there's no Early 2011.

Comment: Anyways either Mac Pro supports way more than 8 GB of RAM. So perhaps you really have a MacBook Pro Early 2011 which would make sense.

Comment: I think this one is mine https://support.apple.com/kb/sp619?locale=en_US

Comment: Okay, you have a MacBook Pro then - a laptop. The Mac Pro is a desktop computer. Your MacBook Pro supports 16 GB RAM just fine (2 x 8 GB modules).

Comment: yup, big difference between a Mac Pro & a MacBook Pro ;)

Comment: oops sorry LOL.. I never know there is Mac Pro on desktop.. I thought it's called as `Mac` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MacBook Pro (Early 2011) support up to 16 GB of RAM just fine. Apple stated 8 GB of RAM as maximum when the model was released, but it has later been confirmed that it actually support 16 GB of RAM without problems. For example check this link:

[MacBook Pro Early 2011 - EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html)

The Mid 2010 and Mid 2012 Mac Pro's support at least 48 GB of RAM.

So all in all, there should be no problems in upgrading to 16 GB of RAM if you have one of these Mac models.

Comment: I've got 64GB in a 2012 Mac Pro in dual-channel, in triple-channel they will take 96GB

Comment: I'm currently working on a 2012 MacPro with extended RAM too. I know it takes more, which is why I wrote "at least". I.e. Apple specifies that it can upgrade to 48 GB (and more depending on which sub-model you have). In reality you can often add more RAM, which is the case here.

Comment: yup, just confirming the actual 'unsupported but works' figures. They can take 16GB sticks, but only 6 of them, or 8 8GB sticks.